# WiFi switched off after Update for 14.04 today

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers

Updates received today.  After directed restart, WiFi did not come turn on.  Can connect to internet using cable to Modem, but no WiFi connection.  Machine is Compaq Presario C727 (32bit) running Ubuntu 14.04.  Broadcom Corp BCM4311.11 b/g wireless lan controller installed, using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary) driver.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

Was your kernel updated?  If so you need to rebuild the broadcom driver module.

There are two options for dealing with broadcom chips.

Option 1 is to use the proprietary driver (bcmwl kernel source) which must be rebuilt after each kernel update.

Option 2 is to use the b43 fw cutter reverse engineered driver.  This driver is kernel agnostic and it looks like your device is supported.  Might be worth using this driver instead of wl (bcmwl kernel source) as it will survive kernel updates.

http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/#Supported_devices shows your device is supported by the b43.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response & help.  I finally ask Google the right question yesterday, and got a step-by-step instruction for uninstalling the existing driver and installing a new one.  PRESTO!  Wireless is back.  Thanks for your help, and I'll save your support "for the future".  Only wish I was more knowledgeable about the program(s).  Thanks again.